# Could not extract share price from DataFrame column using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, pandas

```py
d=df.key.str.extract(pat=r"\[0-9\]\*\[.\]\[0-9\]\[0-9\]",expand=True)
```

```
key                             value
 0   Date 2021-04-05 870.929688 Name: Adj Close,... SBILIFE.NS
 1   Date 2021-04-05 1386.009521 Name: Adj Close... SRTRANSFIN.NS 
 2   Date 2021-04-06 39.354458 Name: Adj Close, ... NACLIND.NS 
 3   Date 2021-04-06 1397.550781 Name: Adj Close... SHRIRAMCIT.NS 
 4   Date 2021-04-07 70.805176 Name: Adj Close, ... EDELWEISS.NS
```

Though the key column is shown above index, its basically the date column(2nd), I want to extract the share price which is there after date in each row and before Name (like 870.929688 in first row) my code is unable to extract data and giving error "pattern contains no capture groups"

please help

```
d=df4.value.str.extract(pat=r"\[0-9\]\*\[.\]\[0-9\]\[0-9\]",expand=True)
```

Comment: Why is your data in this format in the first place? Why not use some API, like yfinance, that gives you the data in a normal format?

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will capture the stock price in the first and only capture group:

`\d+-\d+-\d+\s+(.*?)\s*Name`

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example

```
\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+Name:
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(` Capture **group 1** (for *str.extract*)

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `)`  Close group 1
- `\s+Name:` Match 1+ whitespace chars and `Name:`

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/fVtAp3/1)

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

strings = [
    "Date 2021-04-05 870.929688 Name: Adj Close,... SBILIFE.NS",
    "Date 2021-04-05 1386.009521 Name: Adj Close... SRTRANSFIN.NS ",
    "Date 2021-04-06 39.354458 Name: Adj Close, ... NACLIND.NS ",
    "Date 2021-04-06 1397.550781 Name: Adj Close... SHRIRAMCIT.NS ",
    "Date 2021-04-07 70.805176 Name: Adj Close, ... EDELWEISS.NS"
]

df = pd.DataFrame(strings, columns=["value"])
df['price'] = df.value.str.extract(pat=r"\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+Name:", expand=True)
print(df)
```

Output

```
                                               value        price
0  Date 2021-04-05 870.929688 Name: Adj Close,......   870.929688
1  Date 2021-04-05 1386.009521 Name: Adj Close......  1386.009521
2  Date 2021-04-06 39.354458 Name: Adj Close, ......    39.354458
3  Date 2021-04-06 1397.550781 Name: Adj Close......  1397.550781
4  Date 2021-04-07 70.805176 Name: Adj Close, ......    70.805176
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, mind the **parentheses**:

```py
df["price"]=df["value"].str.extract(r"([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\sName:", expand=False)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/5HltRM/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]*                   any character of: '0' to '9' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Name:                    'Name:'
```